# Directly convert BufferedImage in a File object

Tags: java

I saw many examples on the internet on how to convert a File into a BufferedImage, but I need to make a counter conversion.

I've tried some ways, but all are quite complicated.

I wonder if there is a direct way to accomplish this.

I have this in my code:

```
for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    Date date = new Date();
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadPath + date.getTime() + fileName + ".tmp";
                    File storeFile = new File(filePath);

                    BufferedImage tempImg = ImageIO.read(storeFile);

                    //I make process in the tempImg

                    //I need save it
                    item.write(tempImg);
                }
            }
```

I don't need write a FileItem, but the BufferedImage that I have processed.

Comment: Why not show what you've tried? Why not tell us how they're not working for you? Why make us repeat info you've already read? Note that `ImageIO.write(...)` for writing and `ImageIO.read(...)` for reading has worked well for me.

Comment: Sorry, I will explain better then.

Comment: ok..... so does your code work? fail? throw exceptions? what?

Comment: It isn't giving error because actually the question is how I can do this. To save with FileItem, I need a File, and what I have is a BufferedImage

Comment: ??? So you create a new File. I'm still confused. Have you gone through the Java File tutorial?

Comment: What's `item`? What's `FileItem`?

Comment: Yes. This code is to save an generic file, and and I'm adapting it to be able to image processing. This code is inside a FileItem for, and this File is created to store the information and later be used by FileItem Object to save the file to disk.

Comment: You understand me now?

Comment: No, as per @MadProgrammer -- what is a `FileItem`? Why not show a small compilable and runnable program where you try to read, display and write an image file.

Comment: You can read the image content by using `ImageIO.read(File)`, which would considered the reverse of `ImageIO.write(File)`...

Comment: Look the code now. I put all the code. Is more cleaner for you?

Comment: Generally no.  What is `FileItem`, what does `item.write` actually do?  If you don't write the `BufferedImage` back to the `File` it will never change

Answer (score 3):

```
File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not work man. In disk, no file is written.

Comment: Netbeans? I don't use Netbeans. And yes I have looked in the folder. Display the absolute path, went there, and the file is not.

Comment: Can you update your OP with what your code looks like now?

Comment: What's scaledImg? What you're writing shouldn't even compile. 
First you create "an empty image", like this:
`File outputfile = new File("emptyImage.jpg");`
Then you read the file info and "paint the empty image", like this:
`ImageIO.write(tempImg, "tmp", outputfile);`

Comment: I change: ImageIO.write(tempImg, "jpg", storeFile); //item.write(tempImg);

Comment: And I do this: File storeFile = new File(filePath);